# Rails 3.2.8 "NotImplementedError: method `backtrace' called on unexpected T_NODE object" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting the following error:

> NotImplementedError: method `backtrace' called on unexpected T_NODE object

when using rails console to access one specific model, Domain, with "Domain.new"

Model is defined as:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Environment:

- Rails 3.2.8
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
- Linux cb-2 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC
  2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Full backtrace is at https://gist.github.com/954bcdf833c8aef4d2f9

There are 41 other models in the project which test without any issue

Would very much appreciate it you would be able to shed some light on the issue.

Ross

Comment: Did you ever determine what was going on here? I recently encountered a similar issue, though unfortunately without a good repro case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember correctly, I had similar backtrace.

In my case, the database haven't initialized correctly and `schema_migration` table was corrupted.

Thus, my recommendation is, try run `rake db:migrate:status` and see it shows list of migrations you've created correctly or not. If it is not, then, try re-build database and try again.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am seeing entries in schema migrations table which do not correspond to any file.